# Ft and DTFT of negative frequency

Tags: signal-analysis, fourier-transform, continuous-signals, dtft

I have a question that might sound silly but if I have a real and even signal x(t) can I define the FT and DTFT of the negative frequency if I can show:

$$X(-\omega) =  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(-t)e^{-j\omega t} \,dt $$
And similary fir DTFT
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: Not really, I was studying and trying understand whether this is true because it's a real signal. I mean if the signal wasn't real the  does this corresponds to the comple conjugate of X(ω) but since it is real it reduces to the above?

Comment: No, I don't think it matters if the signal is real or not, I'll add an answer that should clarify this, see if you agree with me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fourier Transform:

$$X(\omega) = \int_{t=-\infty}^\infty x(t)e^{-j\omega t}dt$$

Replace $\omega$ with $-\omega$:

$$X(-\omega) = \int_{t=-\infty}^\infty x(t)e^{j\omega t}dt$$

Replace $t$ with $-t$:

$$X(-\omega) = \int_{-t=\infty}^{-\infty} x(-t)e^{j\omega (-t)}d(-t)$$

$$ = \int_{t=-\infty}^{\infty} x(-t)e^{-j\omega t}dt$$

To describe this property intuitively, observe that $\mathscr{F}\{x(-t)\}$ is the Fourier Transform of a time reversal (playing the signal backwards), and results in a frequency reversal (the spectrum flips around the origin so that positive frequencies become negative frequencies and negative frequencies become positive frequencies.) That said, do not confuse $X(-\omega)$ with "negative frequencies". The expression $X(-\omega)$ simply means to flip the horizontal axis so that the negative frequencies become positive and vice versa.

Consider this very simple case of a single "positive" frequency:

$$x_1(t)= e^{j\omega_o t} \tag{1} \label{1}$$

Where $\omega_o$ is some positive real constant and thus $\ref{1}$ is describing a single phasor of constant magnitude rotating counter clock-wise on the complex plane. THIS is what a positive frequency is: the general form $Ae^{j\theta}$ is a phasor of magnitude $A$ and angle $\theta$. Thus in $\ref{1}$ the phase is increasing linearly with time in the positive direction. (For signal processing in general you will find it much more intuitive to think of spinning phasors, bicycle wheels etc as representing distinct "frequencies" and not sines and cosines; my opinion).

As mentioned, if we observe the phase versus time for $\ref{1}$, it will increase linearly with time. If we instead played this waveform backwards (which is $x(-t)$), the phase would decrease linearly with time, which is what we would refer to as a negative frequency, such as:

$$x_2(t) = x_1(-t)= e^{-j\omega_o t} \tag{2} \label{2}$$

To convince yourself, review the Fourier Transform of $\ref{1}$ and $\ref{2}$ to see that the Fourier Transform for $\ref{1}$ is a single impulse in the positive frequency axis, where the Fourier Transform for $\ref{2}$ is a single impulse in the negative frequency axis. And given by Euler's relationship of exponentials to sinusoids we see how a sinusoid consists of two frequency tones; both a positive and negative frequency:

$$2\cos(\omega_o t) = e^{j\omega_o t} + e^{-j\omega_o t}$$